# IntelliJ: get a warning if I call a method annotated with @VisibleForTesting

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, visibility

I have the following use case:

I want to Unit-test a private method (I really want to).
Now, there are different approaches, but I want to choose the approach "make the method package private".

In Guava, there's an annotation called [@VisibleForTesting](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.java). What I want to do is:
Whenever this method is called **from another class** (in the same package, of course), regardless of it's a subclass of this class or not, **display a warning** like "Hey dude, the method you want to call is marked with @VisibleForTesting, are you sure you want to call it?".

I played a bit with [custom inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html), but with no luck so far. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: um ... that use-case should'nt even be possible since test classes are supposed to be completely seperate from application classes. **Please** tell me you did'nt mix test classes with normal classes

Comment: No, you got me wrong. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a custom inspection, the necessary inspection is built in. Go to
`Preferences | Editor | Inspections` and enable the inspection 
`Java | General | Test-only class or method call in production code`. Now you will get a warning if you try to call members with the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation from production code, but not from test code.

Comment: A follow-up question: the inspection works well and I get a warning or an error, depending on my settings. But: is it possible to even get a compile error when this inspection finds something? Currently, there's no **compile error**, even when I set the inspection to show an error instead of a warning.

Comment: There is currently no way to do that. You may want to vote for [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78625).

Comment: Is there any way to configure IntelliJ to have a similar inspection but for methods with my own `@VisibleForTesting` annotation, and not the guava one ?

Comment: No, there is no way to configure the inspection for this. Please file a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues